# readline() internal buffer

Tags: c, linux, gnu, libreadline

Using [GNU Readline](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html):

The function `readline()` displays prompt and reads user's input.

Can I modify its internal buffer? and how to achieve that?

```
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

int main()
{
    char* input;
        // Display prompt and read input 
        input = readline("please enter your name: ");

        // Check for EOF.
        if (!input)
            break;

        // Add input to history.
        add_history(input);

        // Do stuff...

        // Free input.
        free(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is its "internal buffer"? Maybe it doesn't have one? I don't really understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: using standard `std::cin` we can access its internal buffer using `rdbuf()` function. I don't know if it's possible when using `readline()`

Comment: Check the documentation about [Command line editing](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC1) first please.

Comment: Please erase the "C++" from your title, there is nothing C++-specific in your question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, one can modify readline's edit buffer, e.g. by using the function `rl_insert_text()`. In order to make this useful, I *think* you'll need to use readline's slightly more complicated "callback interface" instead of the all-singing and dancing `readline()` function in your example.

Readline comes with very good and complete [documentation](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC23), therefore I just give a minimal example program to help you to get started   :

```
/* compile with gcc -o test <this program>.c -lreadline */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>

void line_handler(char *line) { /* This function (callback) gets called by readline
                                   whenever rl_callback_read_char sees an ENTER */ 
  printf("You changed this into: '%s'\n", line);
  exit(0);
}

int main() {
  rl_callback_handler_install("Enter a line: ", &line_handler);
  rl_insert_text("Heheheh...");    /* insert some text into readline's edit buffer... */
  rl_redisplay ();                 /* Make sure we see it ... */

  while (1) {
    rl_callback_read_char();       /* read and process one character from stdin */
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to place an input line stuck to terminal's bottom?

Comment: @Kira San: Readline doesn't have any "hooks" that could help you achieve that. You could try to use ncurses to establish e.g. different windows on your terminal, including an input area at the bottom, but that will not be easy. For more on this (including a possible way out) see e.g. http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#readline_library

Comment: Yes, it is not easy, that's why I'm going for GNU Readline. I'm asking so many questions.But is there a function which cancels a readline input request?

Comment: Yes, but the answer is a bit too long for a comment, and I don't yet find an answer on SO. Can you make it a new question?

Comment: Thanks, here is my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661706/gnu-readline-is-there-a-function-that-cancels-readline-input-request