# GNU Readline: Is there a function that cancels readline input request?

Tags: c, linux, libreadline

I'm new to GNU Readline, so I want to know if there exist a function that can cancel `readline()` request?

Comment: Well since the `readline` function is *blocking*, not really. You might be able to do it using multiple threads and sending an interrupt to the terminal. Also, can you please elaborate on *why* you want to "cancel" the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this, you'll have to use the [alternate](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC41) (or "callback") interface to readline. There is actually no need to cancel anything, you just (temporarily) step out of the loop around `rl_callback_read_char` to do whatever needs to be done. This can even happen *before* the user has sent an ENTER, but *only after a keypress*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>

void line_handler(char *line) { /* This function (callback) gets called by readline                    
                                   whenever rl_callback_read_char sees an ENTER */
  printf("%s? Hah!!\n", line);
}

int main() {
  rl_callback_handler_install("Ask a question: ", &line_handler);

  while (1) {
    rl_callback_read_char();
    if (strstr(rl_line_buffer, "you")) { /* They're asking about *me* =:-0 */
      printf("\nNo personal questions please! Goodbye!\n");
      break;
      /* or make a snarky remark and continue */
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to "cancel" without a keypress, you'll have to interrupt the `read()` syscall inside the `rl_callback_read_char()`  using a signal (e.g. by setting an `alarm()`). Be aware, however, that readline [installs its own signal handlers](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC44).

A slightly more sophisticated method would be to insert into the loop a `select()` on *two* file descriptors, `stdin` and e.g. a pipe (the [self-pipe trick](http://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html)), to use this second descriptor (and/or a timeout) to "wake up" the `select()`, and then step out of the loop just like in the example below..

Comment: This is a great example on how to do it. Thank you! :)